# Scroll in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to create an animation on scroll in a click event in React JS **without** JQuery?

I have a navigation and I want to go to a page section depending on what user is clicked. And I want to do it with some animation.

The problem is that the navigation and the section are not in the same file.

I have something like this in main component :

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header currentLanguage={this.props.language.labels}/>
            {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                currentLanguage: this.props.language.labels
            })}
            <Footer currentLanguage={this.props.language.labels}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In this props children are the sections which I want to navigate. They are :

```
return (
            <div className="homeMain">
                <section ref="home" className="marginOnXs">
                    <MainSlider />
                </section>
                <section id="performance" ref="performance">
                    <Performance currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                </section>
                <section id="benefits" ref="benefits">
                    <Benefits currentLanguage={languageHome} />
                </section>
                 <section ref="contact" id="contact">
                        <ContactForm currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                 </section>
            </div>
        );
```

Inside header I have something like this :

```
<ul className="noPadding">
     <li> <Link to="" onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, "home")}>Home </Link></li>
     <li> <Link to="" onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, "contact")}>Contact?</Link></li>
 </ul>
```

And in handle scroll I tried something like :

```
handleScroll(id, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let test = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs[id]);
    let scrollTop = event.target.body.scrollTop,
    itemTranslate = Math.min(0, scrollTop/3 - 60);
    window.scrollTo(0, itemTranslate);
}
```

But it won't work. `this.refs[id]` return undefined. If contact link in header get clicked the parameter id in the function is `contact`, but it can't find `this.refs["contact"]`, because it is in some other component.

Any advice?

Comment: Ref ed component is still mounted while you want to reference right  ? Or It has unmounted and you are trying to reference it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use props to pass down functions and use as a means to communicate between sibling components.

You can use "this.props.handleScroll" and in your root component and pass on the id to scroll to to the children. Something like,

```
    <ul className="noPadding">
      <li> <Link to="" onClick={this.props.handleScroll.bind(this, "home")}>Home </Link></li>
      <li> <Link to="" onClick={this.props.handleScroll.bind(this, "contact")}>Contact?</Link></li>
    </ul>

   <-- In your root component --->
    <Header currentLanguage={this.props.language.labels} handleScroll={::this.handleScroll}} />

    handleScroll(id, event) {
      this.setState({
        scrollToId: id
      })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header currentLanguage={this.props.language.labels}/>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                    currentLanguage: this.props.language.labels,
                    scrollToId: this.state && this.state.scrollToId
                })}
                <Footer currentLanguage={this.props.language.labels}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    <-- In your child component -->

    componentDidUpdate() {
      const idToScroll = this.props.scrollToId;
      // you can access this.refs[idToScroll] here and get the 
      // scrollheight and scroll to the position of the element
    }

    return (
          <div className="homeMain">
              <section ref="home" className="marginOnXs">
                  <MainSlider />
              </section>
              <section id="performance" ref="performance">
                  <Performance currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
              </section>
              <section id="benefits" ref="benefits">
                  <Benefits currentLanguage={languageHome} />
              </section>
               <section ref="contact" id="contact">
                      <ContactForm currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
               </section>
          </div>
    );
```

I think you should go through this to get a better idea for communicating between components, [React.js - Communicating between sibling components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143767/react-js-communicating-between-sibling-components) and the answer to [React.js - Communicating between sibling components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143767/react-js-communicating-between-sibling-components)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I knew that. I asked is there any way to get a ref from the other component. Because I would really like to do it inside the header.

Comment: Ahh. But, to access the refs of a sibling component you have to make sure that the sibling is mounted. You probably need to pass on the refs to the parent component (componentDidMount of children) and handle the scroll part in the root component (not the header again). But again, it is generally considered an anti-pattern in React to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the react libraries [React Reveal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reveal). You can wrap your components in these tags and they will animate while scrolling.

For example :

```html
<Zoom>
  <p>Markup that will be revealed on scroll</p>
</Zoom>
```

Go through the documentation to see all the different ways to reveal while scrolling.

You can also see demos [Here](https://www.react-reveal.com/)