# Calling a method from it's sibling component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Structure

```
ScreenContainer.js
|
|---Header.js
|     |---LogoButton.js
|
|----FeedContainer.js
      |---Feed.js
```

I have a `FlatList` in `Feed.js`

I want to `scrollToOffset()` the `Feed`, when LogoButton is Clicked.

The `ref` of `FlatList` exists only in `Feed.js`

How do I invoke a `Feed.js` Method from the `LogoButton.js` ?

EDIT : I tried storing the `ref` in Redux, but it caused Multiple event dispatches and `undefined` errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js - Communicating between sibling components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143767/react-js-communicating-between-sibling-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be multiple solutions here but potentially since you are using Redux you can do the following:

1. Dispatch an action from `Logo.js` when the logo is pressed, which sets some state variable `isLogoPressed` to true.
2. `FeedContainer.js` registers with the store and passes down the `isLogoPressed` prop to `Feed.js`.
3. In `Feed.js`'s [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method check whether `isLogoPressed` is true and trigger the `ScrollToOffset()` function.
4. Maybe dispatch an action to reset `isLogoPressed` to false once its done.

This gives you the flexibility of having custom behavior whenever the logo is pressed no matter what screen you are on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh yes, I could do that. I currently managed to implement by setting a `ref` to the `Feed.js` in the `FeedContainer.js` and then calling a `Feed`'s instance method using that `ref`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function in your button, just pass the function by props and call it.

Example:
on Feed

```
<LogoButton callback={this.scrollToOffset} />
```

in the button just use  `onPress={this.props.callback()}`