# How to pass eventhandler to sibling component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an eventHandler and I want it's sibling component to handle it. There are a lot of properties (e.g. `this.randomNumber = 555` inside constructor) inside `<Brains />` which are needed for `onLeftLeftMove` to handle the event.

```
render( ) {
  <div>
    <LeftControl onTouchMove={this.onLeftMove} />
    <Brains ..wants to handle onLeftMove because onLeftMove needs access to a lot of properties inside Brains.. />
  </div>
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js - Communicating between sibling components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143767/react-js-communicating-between-sibling-components)

Answer (score 3):

You need to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up). Which means common ancestor - the one which renders `LeftControl` and `Brains` - will hold all the information that will be required by them both.

Comment: I can't lift state up in this specific case.

Comment: @J.Reku Why not? You usually can