# how to know events of one child component in another child Component

Tags: reactjs

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <SidePanel />
        <DashboardContentPanel />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My question is: In sidePanel, there are 6 buttons and according to the buttons clicked, I want to change the content of DashboardContentPanel

I am very novice in ReactJS! help me. just a logic!

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143767/react-js-communicating-between-sibling-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ref` to access the whole component functions

Let's consider that your `DashboardContentPanel` component has a function called `myFunctionButtonOne` and you need to fire this function when button clicked in `SidePanel` component, so the `Dashboard` component will be the mediator between (`SidePanel`, `DashboardContentPanel`) components

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <SidePanel handleButtonOne={this.panel.myFunctionButtonOne} />
        <DashboardContentPanel ref={(panel)=> this.panel = panel} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And as we passed handleButtonOne as a prop we can use it like

```
<button onClick={this.props.handleButtonOne}>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is define a function in Dashboard class and pass this function to Sidepanel component as props. Now when a button is clicked, the function defined in Dashboard class can be triggered. You can accordingly change the state and pass it to DashboardContentPanel as props. Hope that clears it up :)