# ReactJs : Call method from another component having no relation (parent-child)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a component ->

`AppLanding` Component which renders 2 other components -

```
AppActions
AppListings
```

AppActions & AooListings do not have connection between them.

From the click of button in `AppAction` , I want to call method in `AppListings`.

Necessity of this -

`AppListings` contains `Ag-Grid` and `AppActions` contains button actions. On click of button in `AppActions` , I want to call method in `AppListings` which controls columnapi for Ag-Grid in `AppListings`

If it would have parent child relation , I would have passed method to `AppListings` , but in this case I cannot as it does not have relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want sibling components to communicate. You may want to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144048/1065780

The idea is either to use state managers like `redux`, or to make your parent component receive events from one sibling and pass changed props to another sibling, like this:

```js
function AppLanding() {
  const [isSomethingToggled, setIsSomethingToggled] = React.useState(false);

  const handleAction = () => {
    setIsSomethingToggled(!isSomethingToggled);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <AppActions onClick={handleAction} />
      <AppListings isSomethingToggled={isSomethingToggled} />
    </div>
  );
}

function AppActions({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click action</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function AppListings({ isSomethingToggled }) {
  return <div>Is something toggled: {isSomethingToggled ? 'yes' : 'no'}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppLanding />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use redux on click event of button in AppActions page and listen the redux state with useeffect in AppListings page.

```
const AppActions = (props) =>{
    const clickEvent = () => {
        //you can add page restriction
        props.setReduxState({callMethod:true/*, page:"AppActions"*/})
    }

    return <button onClick={clickEvent}>Button</button>
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setReduxState: reduxStateOperations.setReduxState
}

const connector = Redux.connect(null, mapDispatchToProps);
export default connector(AppActions);
```

```
const AppListings = (props) =>{
    const method = () => { console.log("called") }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.reduxState?.callMethod) {
            method()
            props.setReduxState(undefined)
        }
    }, [props.reduxState])

    return <>AppListings Page</>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
        reduxState: state.reduxState.reduxState,
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setReduxState: reduxStateOperations.setReduxState
}

const connector = Redux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
export default connector(AppListings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look into using [`React.Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to create a global provider (or specifically scoped around your layouts)? This way you could store your actions within a reducer.

*hooks/use-context.jsx*

```
import React from 'react'

// Set a relevant initial state
const INITIAL_STATE = {}

// Add actions for your application
const ACTIONS = {
  UPDATE_VAR: 'update-var',
  DELETE_VAR: 'delete-var'
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const next = { ...state } // Shallow copy

  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.UPDATE_VAR:
      next.var = action.data
      break
    case ACTIONS.DELETE_VAR:
      delete next.var
      break
  }

  return next
}

const Context = React.createContext({
  state: { ...INITIAL_STATE },
  dispatch: () => null
})

export const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    reducer, init(false)
  )

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch, ACTION]}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

// Rename to something relevant
const useContext = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useContext(Context)

  return [state, dispatch]
}

export default useContext
```

*pages/index.jsx*: Provide state

```
import { Provider } from '../hooks/use-context'

const Page = () => (
  <Provider>
    <AppActions />
    <AppListings />
  </Provider>
)

export default Page
```

*components/app-actions.jsx*: Update state

```
import useContext from '../hooks/use-context'

const AppActions = () => {
  const [, dispatch] = useContext()

  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch(/* action */)>
      Click Me
    </button>
  )
}

export default AppActions
```

*components/app-listings.jsx*: Consume state

```
import useContext from '../hooks/use-context'

const AppListings = () => {
  const [state] = useContext()

  return (
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)</pre>
  )
}

export default AppListings
```

You could also look into third-party solutions such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).